# template function returning template function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, boost, overloading, metaprogramming

Currently I implemented two template functions, each returning a template function pointer wrapped using boost::variant:

1. Function fa

   ```
   typedef boost::variant<&A<int>,&A<double>> A_T;

   A_T fa(string type)
   {
       switch(type){
           case "int":  return &A<int>;
           case "double": return &A<double>;
           default: return &A<int>;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Function fb

   ```
   typedef boost::variant<&B<int>,&B<double>> B_T;

   B_T fb(string type)
   {
      switch(type){
          case "int":  return &B<int>;
          case "double": return &B<double>;
          default: return &B<int>;
      }
   }
   ```

My question is "Can we merge the two functions into one template function which takes the functor pointer of A or B as template parameter?". The reason why I need this is because I may have more than two functors like A and B.

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like valid C++ code. I recommend you produce a [mcve]

Comment: If this is anything like your actual implementation, your first step is to try running what you already have through your compiler and figure out the several errors that will come up.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
template<template<typename> class F> // template template
using F_T = boost::variant<F<int>&, F<double>&>; // Need C++11 for this (not strictly needed) alias

template<template<typename> class F>
F_T<F> f(std::string type) {
  if(type == "double") return something<F<double>&>();
  else return something<F<int>&>();
}

using A_T = F_T<A>;
A_T at = f<A>("int");
// F_T<int> broken; // invalid: int is not a template<typename> class
// f<int>("int") // invalid: int is not a template<typename> class
```

`A` is `template<typename> class`, so it may be the type argument to `F_T` and `f`, which are both `template<template<typename> class>`. Compare having a function `a => b` and passing it as argument to a function `(a => b) => c`. We say that a function `[](int i) { return i + 5; }` has *type* `int => int`, just like a type `template<typename> class A` has *kind* `* -> *` (concrete type to concrete type). Just like higher-order functions can have types like `(A => A) => A`, higher-kinded types can have kinds like `(* -> *) -> *`, e.g. `F_T`. Normal types like `int` and `A_T<A>` which can be used as type of variables have kind `*`.

Theory aside, it's rather intuitive that you can have template template parameters like this, even if the syntax looks wonky at first.

Comment: Very interesting and thanks for your reply. BTW, what does something represents?                                                                                                 
Did you use template template function (TTF) frequently? I am a little concerned about readability when using TTF. I think a coder should add twice number of comment lines when he use TTF. However, I agree TTF is very convenient.

Comment: 1) You won't use template-templates in C++ very much, because most people don't know they exist, limiting their prevalence. 2) `something` is just pseudo-code. Replace it with a bit of code that can actually create the value you need. 3) Readability is really the fault of the language. If this were e.g. Haskell, I'd just write: `func :: (SomeConstraint f) => String -> Either (f Int) (f Double)`. You may want to add a short comment that explains what the type parameter should be, but it's easy to understand once you know it exists. Don't document language features in your code.